# What I'm trying to do is to generate an array of letters in alphabetical order, reverse alphabetical order, and print out the whole array randomly

Tags: c#, console

```
namespace Practice69
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] alphabet;
            alphabet = new string[] { "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m" };

            // making the keyboard layout alphabetical and print horizontally
            Array.Sort(alphabet);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", alphabet), alphabet[i]);
            }

            // making the alphabet print out reverse alphabetical and horizontally 

            Array.Reverse(alphabet);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", alphabet), alphabet[i]);
            }

            // making the whole alphabet print out radomly

            Random randAlphabet = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", alphabet), alphabet[i]);

                foreach (string value in alphabet)
                {
                    randAlphabet.Next();
                }
```

I'm expecting it to print out a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
and the same thing but also in reverse order, and in random order.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need any loops.
2. You already have the sorting and reverse sorting nailed, just get rid of the loops!
3. The random bit can be written as a LINQ query (a secret loop!)

How about this?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] alphabet;
        alphabet = new char[] { 'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm' };

        // making the keyboard layout alphabetical and print horizontally
        Array.Sort(alphabet);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(' ', alphabet));

        // making the alphabet print out reverse alphabetical and horizontally 
        Array.Reverse(alphabet);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(' ', alphabet));

        // making the whole alphabet print out randomly
        Random randAlphabet = new Random();
        alphabet = alphabet.OrderBy(x => randAlphabet.Next()).ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(' ', alphabet));
    }
}
```